# Шрифт не работает во фрагменте на устройстве android 5.1 но работает на android 9

Tags: android, typeface

Мне нужно подключить шрифт. Когда делал это в активити, то отлично работало на всех устройствах, на которых тестировал.
Когда сделал использование того же шрифта во фрагменте, то на android 9 все работает, а на 5.1 не срабатывает.
Шрифт определяю в

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_face_page, null);
    // а потом
    myTextView = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.textDay);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica_inserat_cyr_upright.ttf");
    myTextView.setTypeface(font);
}
```

Помогите, в чем моя ошибка?

P.S. Если важно, то фрагменты листаются с помощью FragmentPagerAdapter и использую

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Что пишут в логах?

Comment: E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Comment: И это все? Там всегда логов на несколько страниц.

Comment: D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xb8905fb8,api=1)
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8910b38) (w:324 h:88 s:336 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{1ce8b3ad Toast,ident = 9}

Comment: D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xb8910a78 initialize 0xb8925a58
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0xb8925a50,api=1)
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0xb8925a50)
D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0xb8925a50,w=322,h=88)
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8906918) (w:322 h:88 s:336 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)

Comment: Ну это же логи совсем не об этом. Поставьте брейкпойнт в ту строчку и посмотрите в дебаге, что там происходит.

Comment: Смотрели с товарищем логи. Все одинаково, что в активити, что во фрагменте. Никаких проблем не видно
И то, что по ссылке - дает аналогичный результат.
именно во фрагменте беда....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся беда была в том, что сначала было setTypeface, а потом менялся текст setText.
После изменения мест всё заработало. 
То есть setTypeface работает не на конкретный TextView, а на установленный в нем текст.